# Linear combinations of all possible pairs of rows of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `2x1`vector in Matlab called `x`.

```
clear
rng default
x=[5;6]; %[x1;x2]
```

I apply two linear transformations to `x` and obtain the `6x1` vectors `A1` and `A2`.

**Linear transformation 1**

```
B1=10^6* [1 1;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0] - 10^6 * [0 0;
                         1 1;
                         0 0;
                         0 0;
                         0 0;
                         0 0] + [0  0;
                                 0  0;
                                -1  0;
                                 0 -1;
                                -1  1;
                                 0  0];
A1=B1*x; 
%A1=[10^6*(x1+x2); -10^6(x1+x2); -x1; -x2; x2-x1; 0]
```

**Linear transformation 2**

```
B2=10^6* [1 1;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0;
          0 0] - 10^6 * [0 0;
                         1 1;
                         0 0;
                         0 0;
                         0 0;
                         0 0] + [0  0;
                                 0  0;
                                -1  1;
                                 0 -1;
                                -1  0;
                                 0  0];
A2=B2*x; 
%A2=[10^6*(x1+x2); -10^6(x1+x2); x2-x1; -x1; -x2; 0]
```

Let `y` be a `1x2` vector with first element `y1` picked from `A1` and   second element `y2` picked from `A2`. As both `A1` and `A2` have `6` elements, `y` can take `36` values. Let `Y` be the `36x2` matrix listing in each row a possible value of `y`.

Hence,

```
%Y=[10^6*(x1+x2)  10^6*(x1+x2);
%  10^6*(x1+x2)  -10^6*(x1+x2);
%  10^6*(x1+x2)   x2-x1;
%  10^6*(x1+x2)  -x2;
%  10^6*(x1+x2)  -x1;
%  10^6*(x1+x2)  -0;
% -10^6*(x1+x2)   10^6*(x1+x2);
%  ...]
```

I would like your help to write down a code constructing a matrix `C` of size `(2K)x2` such that

- `K=nchoosek(36,2)`, i.e., `K=36!/(2*34!)=630`
- `C*x=D`, where `D` of size `2Kx1` reports, for every possible pair `(i,j)` of rows from `Y`,

`[-Y(i,1)+Y(j,1); 
  -Y(i,2)+Y(j,2)]`

Hence,

```
%D=[-10^6*(x1+x2)+10^6*(x1+x2); %rows 1,2 (first coordinate)
%   -10^6*(x1+x2)-10^6*(x1+x2); %rows 1,2 (second coordinate)
%   -10^6*(x1+x2)+10^6*(x1+x2); %rows 1,3 (first coordinate)
%   -10^6*(x1+x2)+x2-x1;        %rows 1,3 (second coordinate)
%   ...]
```

---

**Comments:** let me clarify that I know which elements should be inside `C` in order to get the desired `D`, but I would like to avoid inserting them "manually". There should be some "pattern" that allows to quickly build `C`.

Also, ideally, I would like the code not to rely on the specific content of `B1` and `B2`, i.e.: suppose I change `B1` and `B2` to other matrices producing different linear transformations of `x`; I would like the code to get `C` to remain valid.

Comment: This starts poorly. You cannot multiply a [6x4] matrix by a a [2x1] vector, so the code crashes from  `A1=B1*x;`. It seems that the two last columns of each of the matrices B1 and B2 should be removed.

Comment: So sorry, it was left from my previous version of the question. Now fixed